# How to zoom the path inside canvas?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I have drawn a path using html5 canvas and javascript. I want to zoom that path. The black colored map should be 100% of the view box. When I mention any view box size, the map should be adjusted to 100% as svgs. Please check the below plunker

[Check this plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/rjhkDBEn9j9D7qZZ09tD?p=preview)

```js
// Global variables
var canvas;
var ctx;
// This function is called when the page loads.
function init() {

    // Initialize canvas and get context.
    canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

    // Draw on the context.
    draw(ctx);
}

function draw(ctx) {

    // Draw on the canvas.
    // Get the drawing coordinates.
    ctx.save();
    ctx.translate(0, 0);
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(0, 0);
    ctx.lineTo(23.03, 0);
    ctx.lineTo(23.03, 22.464);
    ctx.lineTo(0, 22.464);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.clip();
    ctx.translate(0, 0);
    ctx.translate(0, 0);
    ctx.scale(1, 1);
    ctx.translate(0, 0);
    ctx.strokeStyle = 'rgba(0,0,0,0)';
    ctx.lineCap = 'butt';
    ctx.lineJoin = 'miter';
    ctx.miterLimit = 4;
    ctx.save();
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(14.708, 2.174);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(14.518, 2.2119999999999997, 14.328, 2.25, 14.138, 2.288);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(14.138, 2.3259999999999996, 14.138, 2.364, 14.138, 2.4019999999999997);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(14.1, 2.4019999999999997, 14.062, 2.4019999999999997, 14.024, 2.4019999999999997);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(14.024, 2.5919999999999996, 14.024, 2.7819999999999996, 14.024, 2.9719999999999995);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(14.276, 3.1989999999999994, 14.299, 3.5759999999999996, 14.594, 3.7699999999999996);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(14.724, 3.8999999999999995, 14.594, 3.8149999999999995, 14.822, 3.8839999999999995);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(14.889999999999999, 4.1419999999999995, 14.918999999999999, 4.164999999999999, 15.049999999999999, 4.34);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(15.088, 4.34, 15.126, 4.34, 15.164, 4.34);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(15.164, 4.4159999999999995, 15.164, 4.492, 15.164, 4.568);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(15.202, 4.568, 15.24, 4.568, 15.278, 4.568);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(15.316, 5.024, 15.354000000000001, 5.4799999999999995, 15.392000000000001, 5.936);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(15.354000000000001, 5.936, 15.316, 5.936, 15.278, 5.936);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(15.24, 6.088, 15.202, 6.24, 15.164, 6.392);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(15.126, 6.392, 15.088, 6.392, 15.049999999999999, 6.392);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(14.995, 6.641, 15.351999999999999, 7.0760000000000005, 15.392, 7.19);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(15.392, 7.3420000000000005, 15.392, 7.494000000000001, 15.392, 7.646000000000001);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(15.164, 7.722, 14.936, 7.798000000000001, 14.708, 7.8740000000000006);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(14.898, 8.33, 15.088000000000001, 8.786000000000001, 15.278, 9.242);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(15.784, 9.008000000000001, 15.92, 9.010000000000002, 16.532, 9.128);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(16.532, 9.242, 16.532, 9.356, 16.532, 9.47);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(16.709, 9.571000000000002, 16.771, 9.637, 16.874, 9.812000000000001);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(17.003, 9.716000000000001, 16.891, 9.826, 16.988, 9.698);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(17.126, 9.625, 17.152, 9.512, 17.216, 9.47);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(17.292, 9.47, 17.368000000000002, 9.47, 17.444000000000003, 9.47);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(17.444000000000003, 9.432, 17.444000000000003, 9.394, 17.444000000000003, 9.356);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(17.520000000000003, 9.356, 17.596000000000004, 9.356, 17.672000000000004, 9.356);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(17.710000000000004, 9.28, 17.748000000000005, 9.204, 17.786000000000005, 9.128);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(17.938000000000006, 9.09, 18.090000000000003, 9.052, 18.242000000000004, 9.014);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(18.280000000000005, 8.937999999999999, 18.318000000000005, 8.862, 18.356000000000005, 8.786);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(18.432000000000006, 8.786, 18.508000000000006, 8.786, 18.584000000000007, 8.786);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(18.546000000000006, 8.709999999999999, 18.508000000000006, 8.634, 18.470000000000006, 8.558);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(18.584000000000007, 8.52, 18.698000000000008, 8.482, 18.812000000000005, 8.443999999999999);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(18.812000000000005, 8.405999999999999, 18.812000000000005, 8.367999999999999, 18.812000000000005, 8.329999999999998);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(18.926000000000005, 8.253999999999998, 19.040000000000006, 8.177999999999999, 19.154000000000003, 8.101999999999999);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(19.154000000000003, 8.025999999999998, 19.154000000000003, 7.949999999999998, 19.154000000000003, 7.873999999999999);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(19.268000000000004, 7.797999999999999, 19.382000000000005, 7.721999999999999, 19.496000000000002, 7.645999999999999);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(19.458000000000002, 7.569999999999999, 19.42, 7.493999999999999, 19.382, 7.417999999999999);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(19.458000000000002, 7.417999999999999, 19.534000000000002, 7.417999999999999, 19.610000000000003, 7.417999999999999);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(19.610000000000003, 7.379999999999999, 19.610000000000003, 7.342, 19.610000000000003, 7.303999999999999);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(19.844000000000005, 7.108999999999999, 19.962000000000003, 7.093999999999999, 20.408, 7.076);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(20.332, 7.494, 20.256, 7.912, 20.18, 8.328999999999999);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(20.368, 8.480999999999998, 20.472, 8.722999999999999, 20.636, 8.899);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(20.712, 8.937, 20.788, 8.975, 20.864, 9.013);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(20.864, 9.089, 20.864, 9.165, 20.864, 9.241);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(20.94, 9.279, 21.016000000000002, 9.317, 21.092000000000002, 9.355);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(21.092000000000002, 9.659, 21.092000000000002, 9.963000000000001, 21.092000000000002, 10.267000000000001);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(21.130000000000003, 10.267000000000001, 21.168000000000003, 10.267000000000001, 21.206000000000003, 10.267000000000001);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(21.244000000000003, 10.381000000000002, 21.282000000000004, 10.495000000000001, 21.320000000000004, 10.609000000000002);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(21.396000000000004, 10.609000000000002, 21.472000000000005, 10.609000000000002, 21.548000000000005, 10.609000000000002);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(21.510000000000005, 10.685000000000002, 21.472000000000005, 10.761000000000001, 21.434000000000005, 10.837000000000002);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(21.586000000000006, 10.875000000000002, 21.738000000000003, 10.913000000000002, 21.890000000000004, 10.951000000000002);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(21.928000000000004, 11.027000000000003, 21.966000000000005, 11.103000000000002, 22.004000000000005, 11.179000000000002);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(22.080000000000005, 11.179000000000002, 22.156000000000006, 11.179000000000002, 22.232000000000006, 11.179000000000002);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(22.270000000000007, 11.255000000000003, 22.308000000000007, 11.331000000000001, 22.346000000000007, 11.407000000000002);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(22.498000000000008, 11.521000000000003, 22.650000000000006, 11.635000000000002, 22.802000000000007, 11.749000000000002);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(22.802000000000007, 11.825000000000003, 22.802000000000007, 11.901000000000002, 22.802000000000007, 11.977000000000002);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(22.878000000000007, 12.015000000000002, 22.954000000000008, 12.053000000000003, 23.03000000000001, 12.091000000000003);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(23.03000000000001, 12.205000000000004, 23.03000000000001, 12.319000000000003, 23.03000000000001, 12.433000000000003);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(21.83300000000001, 12.409000000000004, 21.232000000000006, 12.605000000000004, 20.40800000000001, 12.889000000000003);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(20.256000000000007, 12.889000000000003, 20.10400000000001, 12.889000000000003, 19.95200000000001, 12.889000000000003);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(19.95200000000001, 12.927000000000003, 19.95200000000001, 12.965000000000003, 19.95200000000001, 13.003000000000004);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(19.800000000000008, 13.041000000000004, 19.64800000000001, 13.079000000000004, 19.49600000000001, 13.117000000000004);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(19.49600000000001, 13.193000000000005, 19.49600000000001, 13.269000000000004, 19.49600000000001, 13.345000000000004);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(19.42000000000001, 13.307000000000004, 19.34400000000001, 13.269000000000004, 19.268000000000008, 13.231000000000003);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(19.268000000000008, 13.269000000000004, 19.268000000000008, 13.307000000000004, 19.268000000000008, 13.345000000000004);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(19.230000000000008, 13.345000000000004, 19.192000000000007, 13.345000000000004, 19.154000000000007, 13.345000000000004);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(19.154000000000007, 13.421000000000005, 19.154000000000007, 13.497000000000003, 19.154000000000007, 13.573000000000004);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(19.116000000000007, 13.573000000000004, 19.078000000000007, 13.573000000000004, 19.040000000000006, 13.573000000000004);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(19.040000000000006, 13.535000000000004, 19.040000000000006, 13.497000000000003, 19.040000000000006, 13.459000000000003);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(18.851000000000006, 13.359000000000004, 18.942000000000007, 13.614000000000003, 18.926000000000005, 13.687000000000003);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(18.611000000000004, 13.770000000000003, 18.671000000000006, 13.719000000000003, 18.584000000000007, 14.029000000000003);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(18.546000000000006, 14.029000000000003, 18.508000000000006, 14.029000000000003, 18.470000000000006, 14.029000000000003);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(18.508000000000006, 14.105000000000004, 18.546000000000006, 14.181000000000003, 18.584000000000007, 14.257000000000003);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(18.508000000000006, 14.257000000000003, 18.432000000000006, 14.257000000000003, 18.356000000000005, 14.257000000000003);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(18.344000000000005, 14.418000000000003, 18.335000000000004, 14.296000000000003, 18.470000000000006, 14.371000000000004);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(18.341000000000005, 14.500000000000004, 18.471000000000007, 14.419000000000004, 18.242000000000004, 14.485000000000005);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(18.204000000000004, 14.675000000000004, 18.166000000000004, 14.865000000000006, 18.128000000000004, 15.055000000000005);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(18.090000000000003, 15.055000000000005, 18.052000000000003, 15.055000000000005, 18.014000000000003, 15.055000000000005);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(18.014000000000003, 15.359000000000005, 18.014000000000003, 15.663000000000006, 18.014000000000003, 15.967000000000006);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(17.976000000000003, 15.967000000000006, 17.938000000000002, 15.967000000000006, 17.900000000000002, 15.967000000000006);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(17.862000000000002, 16.119000000000007, 17.824, 16.271000000000004, 17.786, 16.423000000000005);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(17.748, 16.423000000000005, 17.71, 16.423000000000005, 17.672, 16.423000000000005);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(17.71, 16.499000000000006, 17.748, 16.575000000000006, 17.786, 16.651000000000007);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(17.672, 16.689000000000007, 17.558, 16.727000000000007, 17.444000000000003, 16.765000000000008);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(17.406000000000002, 16.95500000000001, 17.368000000000002, 17.145000000000007, 17.330000000000002, 17.335000000000008);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(17.254, 17.373000000000008, 17.178, 17.41100000000001, 17.102, 17.44900000000001);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(17.102, 17.48700000000001, 17.102, 17.52500000000001, 17.102, 17.56300000000001);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(17.14, 17.56300000000001, 17.178, 17.56300000000001, 17.216, 17.56300000000001);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(17.397000000000002, 17.70900000000001, 16.991, 17.67600000000001, 16.988, 17.67700000000001);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(16.988, 17.943000000000012, 16.988, 18.20900000000001, 16.988, 18.47500000000001);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(16.553, 18.66400000000001, 15.911, 19.17300000000001, 15.847999999999999, 19.72900000000001);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(15.771999999999998, 19.72900000000001, 15.696, 19.72900000000001, 15.62, 19.72900000000001);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(15.475999999999999, 19.98900000000001, 14.79, 20.38500000000001, 15.049999999999999, 20.64100000000001);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(14.973999999999998, 20.64100000000001, 14.898, 20.64100000000001, 14.822, 20.64100000000001);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(14.822, 20.90700000000001, 14.822, 21.17300000000001, 14.822, 21.439000000000007);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(14.86, 21.439000000000007, 14.898, 21.439000000000007, 14.936, 21.439000000000007);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(14.936, 21.515000000000008, 14.936, 21.591000000000008, 14.936, 21.66700000000001);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(14.974, 21.66700000000001, 15.012, 21.66700000000001, 15.05, 21.66700000000001);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(15.05, 21.70500000000001, 15.05, 21.74300000000001, 15.05, 21.78100000000001);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(15.012, 21.78100000000001, 14.974, 21.78100000000001, 14.936, 21.78100000000001);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(14.822, 21.922000000000008, 14.692, 21.899000000000008, 14.594, 22.00900000000001);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(14.594, 22.08500000000001, 14.594, 22.161000000000012, 14.594, 22.237000000000013);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(14.517999999999999, 22.199000000000012, 14.442, 22.161000000000012, 14.366, 22.12300000000001);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(14.328, 22.237000000000013, 14.29, 22.351000000000013, 14.251999999999999, 22.46500000000001);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(14.206, 22.49600000000001, 13.994, 22.29700000000001, 13.796, 22.35100000000001);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(13.796, 22.38900000000001, 13.796, 22.42700000000001, 13.796, 22.46500000000001);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(13.34, 22.46500000000001, 12.883999999999999, 22.46500000000001, 12.427999999999999, 22.46500000000001);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(12.422999999999998, 21.91000000000001, 12.568, 21.35400000000001, 12.77, 20.98300000000001);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(12.808, 20.98300000000001, 12.846, 20.98300000000001, 12.884, 20.98300000000001);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(12.884, 20.90700000000001, 12.884, 20.83100000000001, 12.884, 20.75500000000001);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(12.96, 20.71700000000001, 13.036, 20.67900000000001, 13.112, 20.64100000000001);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(13.233, 20.44400000000001, 13.32, 19.90400000000001, 13.226, 19.84300000000001);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(13.302000000000001, 19.84300000000001, 13.378, 19.84300000000001, 13.454, 19.84300000000001);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(13.476, 19.14000000000001, 13.577, 18.68600000000001, 13.454, 18.02000000000001);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(13.378, 18.02000000000001, 13.302000000000001, 18.02000000000001, 13.226, 18.02000000000001);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(13.104000000000001, 17.91500000000001, 13.340000000000002, 17.90600000000001, 13.340000000000002, 17.90600000000001);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(13.340000000000002, 17.86800000000001, 13.340000000000002, 17.83000000000001, 13.340000000000002, 17.79200000000001);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(13.117, 17.38900000000001, 13.420000000000002, 16.60700000000001, 13.226, 16.19600000000001);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(13.112, 16.120000000000008, 12.998000000000001, 16.044000000000008, 12.884, 15.968000000000009);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(12.597, 15.530000000000008, 12.32, 14.62400000000001, 12.314, 13.917000000000009);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(12.238, 13.955000000000009, 12.162, 13.99300000000001, 12.086, 14.03100000000001);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(12.086, 13.955000000000009, 12.086, 13.87900000000001, 12.086, 13.80300000000001);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(11.82, 13.61300000000001, 11.554, 13.423000000000009, 11.288, 13.23300000000001);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(11.288, 13.157000000000009, 11.288, 13.08100000000001, 11.288, 13.00500000000001);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(11.212, 12.96700000000001, 11.136000000000001, 12.92900000000001, 11.06, 12.891000000000009);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(11.06, 12.815000000000008, 11.06, 12.73900000000001, 11.06, 12.66300000000001);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(11.022, 12.66300000000001, 10.984, 12.66300000000001, 10.946, 12.66300000000001);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(10.87, 12.43500000000001, 10.794, 12.20700000000001, 10.718, 11.97900000000001);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(10.68, 11.97900000000001, 10.642, 11.97900000000001, 10.604, 11.97900000000001);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(10.604, 11.865000000000009, 10.604, 11.75100000000001, 10.604, 11.63700000000001);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(10.489999999999998, 11.599000000000009, 10.376, 11.561000000000009, 10.261999999999999, 11.523000000000009);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(10.299999999999999, 11.447000000000008, 10.338, 11.37100000000001, 10.376, 11.295000000000009);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(10.299999999999999, 11.257000000000009, 10.224, 11.219000000000008, 10.148, 11.181000000000008);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(10.148, 11.105000000000008, 10.148, 11.029000000000009, 10.148, 10.953000000000008);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(10.11, 10.953000000000008, 10.072, 10.953000000000008, 10.033999999999999, 10.953000000000008);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(9.749999999999998, 10.619000000000009, 9.267999999999999, 10.154000000000009, 8.78, 10.041000000000007);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(8.78, 9.965000000000007, 8.78, 9.889000000000008, 8.78, 9.813000000000008);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(8.665, 9.772, 8.551, 9.734, 8.437, 9.696);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(8.437, 9.658, 8.437, 9.62, 8.437, 9.581999999999999);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(8.277, 9.459999999999999, 7.997999999999999, 9.29, 7.866999999999999, 9.467999999999998);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(7.866999999999999, 9.391999999999998, 7.866999999999999, 9.315999999999999, 7.866999999999999, 9.239999999999998);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(7.411, 9.164, 6.955, 9.088, 6.499, 9.012);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(6.499, 8.974, 6.499, 8.936, 6.499, 8.898);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(6.271, 8.822, 6.042, 8.746, 5.814, 8.67);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(5.814, 8.632, 5.814, 8.594, 5.814, 8.556);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(5.207, 8.594, 4.599, 8.632, 3.99, 8.67);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(3.99, 8.632, 3.99, 8.594, 3.99, 8.556);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(3.602, 8.441, 3.248, 8.621, 2.964, 8.442);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(2.888, 8.328, 2.813, 8.214, 2.736, 8.101);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(2.66, 8.138, 2.584, 8.176, 2.508, 8.214);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(2.508, 8.1, 2.508, 7.986000000000001, 2.508, 7.872000000000001);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(2.356, 7.834, 2.204, 7.796, 2.052, 7.758);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(2.014, 7.645, 1.976, 7.53, 1.938, 7.417);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(1.976, 7.417, 2.014, 7.417, 2.052, 7.417);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(2.052, 7.075, 2.052, 6.733, 2.052, 6.391);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(2.0140000000000002, 6.391, 1.976, 6.391, 1.938, 6.391);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(1.938, 6.315, 1.938, 6.239, 1.938, 6.163);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(1.9, 6.163, 1.8619999999999999, 6.163, 1.8239999999999998, 6.163);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(1.8239999999999998, 5.897, 1.8239999999999998, 5.631, 1.8239999999999998, 5.365);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(1.513, 5.185, 1.545, 5.053, 1.026, 5.023);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(1.026, 5.061, 1.026, 5.098999999999999, 1.026, 5.137);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(0.95, 5.175, 0.874, 5.213, 0.798, 5.251);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(0.798, 5.175000000000001, 0.798, 5.099, 0.798, 5.023000000000001);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(0.569, 4.958, 0.7, 5.037, 0.57, 4.909);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(0.608, 4.909, 0.6459999999999999, 4.909, 0.6839999999999999, 4.909);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(0.6839999999999999, 4.795, 0.6839999999999999, 4.681, 0.6839999999999999, 4.567);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(0.49399999999999994, 4.567, 0.30399999999999994, 4.567, 0.11399999999999999, 4.567);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(0.076, 4.453, 0.038, 4.339, 0, 4.226);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(0.038, 4.226, 0.076, 4.226, 0.114, 4.226);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(0.114, 4.074, 0.114, 3.922, 0.114, 3.77);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(0.228, 3.732, 0.342, 3.694, 0.456, 3.656);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(0.67, 3.484, 0.76, 3.218, 0.798, 2.858);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(0.988, 2.858, 1.178, 2.858, 1.3679999999999999, 2.858);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(1.3679999999999999, 2.782, 1.3679999999999999, 2.706, 1.3679999999999999, 2.63);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(1.482, 2.63, 1.5959999999999999, 2.63, 1.71, 2.63);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(1.71, 2.554, 1.71, 2.4779999999999998, 1.71, 2.4019999999999997);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(1.8679999999999999, 2.4309999999999996, 1.697, 2.417, 1.824, 2.5159999999999996);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(1.976, 2.44, 2.128, 2.364, 2.28, 2.288);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(2.28, 2.25, 2.28, 2.2119999999999997, 2.28, 2.174);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(2.356, 2.174, 2.432, 2.174, 2.508, 2.174);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(2.573, 1.896, 2.628, 1.923, 2.736, 1.718);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(2.888, 1.832, 3.041, 1.946, 3.192, 2.06);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(3.192, 2.098, 3.192, 2.136, 3.192, 2.174);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(3.269, 2.136, 3.344, 2.098, 3.42, 2.06);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(3.42, 2.136, 3.42, 2.212, 3.42, 2.2880000000000003);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(3.551, 2.42, 3.728, 2.389, 3.99, 2.402);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(3.99, 2.326, 3.99, 2.25, 3.99, 2.174);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(4.12, 2.27, 4.007, 2.159, 4.104, 2.288);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(4.5200000000000005, 2.694, 4.5520000000000005, 3.5309999999999997, 4.674, 4.226);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(4.788, 4.264, 4.902, 4.302, 5.016, 4.34);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(5.055, 4.453, 5.092, 4.567, 5.13, 4.681);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(5.244, 4.643, 5.358, 4.605, 5.4719999999999995, 4.567);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(5.481, 4.867, 5.515999999999999, 4.955, 5.585999999999999, 5.1370000000000005);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(5.8149999999999995, 5.072, 5.909, 5.0520000000000005, 6.042, 4.909000000000001);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(6.042, 4.833000000000001, 6.042, 4.757000000000001, 6.042, 4.681000000000001);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(6.08, 4.681000000000001, 6.117999999999999, 4.681000000000001, 6.156, 4.681000000000001);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(6.156, 4.719000000000001, 6.156, 4.757000000000001, 6.156, 4.795000000000001);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(6.231999999999999, 4.757000000000001, 6.308, 4.719000000000001, 6.3839999999999995, 4.681000000000001);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(6.3839999999999995, 4.719000000000001, 6.3839999999999995, 4.757000000000001, 6.3839999999999995, 4.795000000000001);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(6.5089999999999995, 4.897000000000001, 6.4079999999999995, 4.775000000000001, 6.497999999999999, 4.909000000000001);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(6.459999999999999, 4.909000000000001, 6.422, 4.909000000000001, 6.3839999999999995, 4.909000000000001);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(6.273, 5.098, 6.549, 5.005, 6.613, 5.023);
    ctx.lineTo(6.727, 4.909);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(6.765000000000001, 5.099, 6.803, 5.289, 6.841, 5.479);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(6.955, 5.517, 7.069, 5.555, 7.183, 5.593);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(7.183, 5.631, 7.183, 5.669, 7.183, 5.707);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(7.322, 5.818, 7.404, 5.787, 7.5249999999999995, 5.935);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(7.866999999999999, 5.973, 8.209, 6.010999999999999, 8.551, 6.0489999999999995);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(8.589, 5.935, 8.627, 5.821, 8.665000000000001, 5.707);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(8.936, 5.684, 8.947, 5.66, 9.121, 5.593);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(9.011000000000001, 5.447, 8.871, 5.475, 8.779, 5.365);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(8.779, 5.289000000000001, 8.779, 5.213, 8.779, 5.1370000000000005);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(8.665, 5.099, 8.551, 5.061, 8.437, 5.023);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(8.442, 4.58, 8.474, 4.454, 8.665, 4.226);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(8.741, 4.188, 8.816999999999998, 4.15, 8.892999999999999, 4.112);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(8.855, 3.998, 8.817, 3.883, 8.779, 3.77);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(8.779, 3.77, 8.967, 3.622, 9.007, 3.542);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(8.663, 3.463, 8.258, 2.789, 7.981, 3.085);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(7.981, 3.009, 7.981, 2.933, 7.981, 2.8569999999999998);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(7.796, 2.98, 7.92, 3.051, 7.867, 3.085);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(7.795, 3.131, 7.627, 2.877, 7.411, 2.971);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(7.335, 3.085, 7.259, 3.2, 7.183, 3.313);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(7.02, 3.367, 7.021, 3.121, 6.955, 3.085);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(6.8790000000000004, 3.085, 6.803, 3.085, 6.727, 3.085);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(6.727, 3.047, 6.727, 3.009, 6.727, 2.971);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(6.362, 2.781, 6.006, 2.7560000000000002, 5.473000000000001, 2.743);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(5.473000000000001, 2.667, 5.473000000000001, 2.5909999999999997, 5.473000000000001, 2.5149999999999997);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(5.549, 2.5149999999999997, 5.625000000000001, 2.5149999999999997, 5.7010000000000005, 2.5149999999999997);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(5.793, 2.1479999999999997, 5.993, 2.1099999999999994, 6.157000000000001, 1.8309999999999995);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(6.081000000000001, 1.8309999999999995, 6.005000000000001, 1.8309999999999995, 5.929000000000001, 1.8309999999999995);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(5.883000000000001, 1.3729999999999996, 5.7970000000000015, 1.4189999999999996, 5.929000000000001, 1.0329999999999995);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(6.004, 1.072, 6.081, 1.11, 6.157, 1.148);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(6.195, 1.262, 6.232, 1.376, 6.271, 1.49);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(6.3469999999999995, 1.49, 6.423, 1.49, 6.499, 1.49);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(6.46, 1.566, 6.423, 1.642, 6.385, 1.718);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(6.423, 1.718, 6.460999999999999, 1.718, 6.499, 1.718);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(6.632, 1.873, 6.707, 1.892, 6.955, 1.946);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(6.955, 1.8319999999999999, 6.955, 1.718, 6.955, 1.6039999999999999);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(7.107, 1.6039999999999999, 7.259, 1.6039999999999999, 7.4110000000000005, 1.6039999999999999);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(7.373, 1.49, 7.335, 1.376, 7.297, 1.262);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(7.373, 1.3, 7.449, 1.338, 7.525, 1.376);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(7.525, 1.3379999999999999, 7.525, 1.2999999999999998, 7.525, 1.2619999999999998);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(7.563000000000001, 1.2619999999999998, 7.601, 1.2619999999999998, 7.639, 1.2619999999999998);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(7.601, 1.0719999999999998, 7.563000000000001, 0.8819999999999998, 7.525, 0.6919999999999998);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(7.563000000000001, 0.6919999999999998, 7.601, 0.6919999999999998, 7.639, 0.6919999999999998);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(7.769, 0.5619999999999998, 7.639, 0.6469999999999998, 7.867, 0.5779999999999998);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(7.867, 0.5019999999999999, 7.867, 0.4259999999999998, 7.867, 0.34999999999999987);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(8.358, 0.48099999999999987, 8.256, 0.32099999999999984, 8.665, 0.12199999999999986);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(8.665, 0.08399999999999985, 8.665, 0.04599999999999986, 8.665, 0.007999999999999854);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(8.827, -0.04900000000000015, 8.828999999999999, 0.21099999999999985, 8.892999999999999, 0.23599999999999988);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(9.26, 0.383, 9.427, 0.259, 9.691, 0.351);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(9.833, 0.7629999999999999, 9.678, 0.997, 9.805000000000001, 1.376);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(10.909000000000002, 0.9259999999999999, 11.771, 1.458, 12.769000000000002, 1.718);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(12.906000000000002, 1.4689999999999999, 13.020000000000001, 1.343, 13.339000000000002, 1.262);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(13.339000000000002, 1.3, 13.339000000000002, 1.338, 13.339000000000002, 1.3760000000000001);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(13.491000000000001, 1.3760000000000001, 13.643000000000002, 1.3760000000000001, 13.795000000000002, 1.3760000000000001);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(13.795000000000002, 1.4140000000000001, 13.795000000000002, 1.4520000000000002, 13.795000000000002, 1.4900000000000002);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(14.232, 1.7, 14.57, 1.656, 14.708, 2.174);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.restore();
    ctx.restore();
}

function paintLake() {

    // If the shape is clicked, display a fact
    // and paint the lake.
    // Display a fact.
    alert("Lake Michigan is one of the five Great Lakes of America.");

    // Fill the lake with blue.
    ctx.fillStyle = "blue";
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.scale(200, 200);
}

function makeLake() {

    // These methods draw the shape of the lake.

}
```

```html
<body onload="init()">
 <h1>
  Lake Michigan
 </h1>
 <canvas id="canvas" width="25" height="25" onclick="paintLake()">
 </canvas>
 <p>
    Click on the lake to learn a fact about Lake Michigan.
 </p>
</body>
```

Comment: Please tell me the reason for negative votes. I can update my question

Answer (score 1):

***DEMO***

```js
// Global variables
var canvas;
var ctx;
// This function is called when the page loads.
function init() {

    // Initialize canvas and get context.
    canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

    // Draw on the context.
    draw(ctx);
}

function draw(ctx) {

    // Draw on the canvas.
    // Get the drawing coordinates.
    ctx.save();
    ctx.translate(0, 0);
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(0, 0);
    ctx.lineTo(23.03, 0);
    ctx.lineTo(23.03, 22.464);
    ctx.lineTo(0, 22.464);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.clip();
    ctx.translate(0, 0);
    ctx.translate(0, 0);
    ctx.scale(1, 1);
    ctx.translate(0, 0);
    ctx.strokeStyle = 'rgba(0,0,0,0)';
    ctx.lineCap = 'butt';
    ctx.lineJoin = 'miter';
    ctx.miterLimit = 4;
    ctx.save();
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(14.708, 2.174);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(14.518, 2.2119999999999997, 14.328, 2.25, 14.138, 2.288);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(14.138, 2.3259999999999996, 14.138, 2.364, 14.138, 2.4019999999999997);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(14.1, 2.4019999999999997, 14.062, 2.4019999999999997, 14.024, 2.4019999999999997);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(14.024, 2.5919999999999996, 14.024, 2.7819999999999996, 14.024, 2.9719999999999995);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(14.276, 3.1989999999999994, 14.299, 3.5759999999999996, 14.594, 3.7699999999999996);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(14.724, 3.8999999999999995, 14.594, 3.8149999999999995, 14.822, 3.8839999999999995);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(14.889999999999999, 4.1419999999999995, 14.918999999999999, 4.164999999999999, 15.049999999999999, 4.34);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(15.088, 4.34, 15.126, 4.34, 15.164, 4.34);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(15.164, 4.4159999999999995, 15.164, 4.492, 15.164, 4.568);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(15.202, 4.568, 15.24, 4.568, 15.278, 4.568);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(15.316, 5.024, 15.354000000000001, 5.4799999999999995, 15.392000000000001, 5.936);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(15.354000000000001, 5.936, 15.316, 5.936, 15.278, 5.936);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(15.24, 6.088, 15.202, 6.24, 15.164, 6.392);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(15.126, 6.392, 15.088, 6.392, 15.049999999999999, 6.392);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(14.995, 6.641, 15.351999999999999, 7.0760000000000005, 15.392, 7.19);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(15.392, 7.3420000000000005, 15.392, 7.494000000000001, 15.392, 7.646000000000001);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(15.164, 7.722, 14.936, 7.798000000000001, 14.708, 7.8740000000000006);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(14.898, 8.33, 15.088000000000001, 8.786000000000001, 15.278, 9.242);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(15.784, 9.008000000000001, 15.92, 9.010000000000002, 16.532, 9.128);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(16.532, 9.242, 16.532, 9.356, 16.532, 9.47);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(16.709, 9.571000000000002, 16.771, 9.637, 16.874, 9.812000000000001);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(17.003, 9.716000000000001, 16.891, 9.826, 16.988, 9.698);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(17.126, 9.625, 17.152, 9.512, 17.216, 9.47);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(17.292, 9.47, 17.368000000000002, 9.47, 17.444000000000003, 9.47);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(17.444000000000003, 9.432, 17.444000000000003, 9.394, 17.444000000000003, 9.356);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(17.520000000000003, 9.356, 17.596000000000004, 9.356, 17.672000000000004, 9.356);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(17.710000000000004, 9.28, 17.748000000000005, 9.204, 17.786000000000005, 9.128);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(17.938000000000006, 9.09, 18.090000000000003, 9.052, 18.242000000000004, 9.014);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(18.280000000000005, 8.937999999999999, 18.318000000000005, 8.862, 18.356000000000005, 8.786);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(18.432000000000006, 8.786, 18.508000000000006, 8.786, 18.584000000000007, 8.786);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(18.546000000000006, 8.709999999999999, 18.508000000000006, 8.634, 18.470000000000006, 8.558);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(18.584000000000007, 8.52, 18.698000000000008, 8.482, 18.812000000000005, 8.443999999999999);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(18.812000000000005, 8.405999999999999, 18.812000000000005, 8.367999999999999, 18.812000000000005, 8.329999999999998);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(18.926000000000005, 8.253999999999998, 19.040000000000006, 8.177999999999999, 19.154000000000003, 8.101999999999999);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(19.154000000000003, 8.025999999999998, 19.154000000000003, 7.949999999999998, 19.154000000000003, 7.873999999999999);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(19.268000000000004, 7.797999999999999, 19.382000000000005, 7.721999999999999, 19.496000000000002, 7.645999999999999);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(19.458000000000002, 7.569999999999999, 19.42, 7.493999999999999, 19.382, 7.417999999999999);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(19.458000000000002, 7.417999999999999, 19.534000000000002, 7.417999999999999, 19.610000000000003, 7.417999999999999);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(19.610000000000003, 7.379999999999999, 19.610000000000003, 7.342, 19.610000000000003, 7.303999999999999);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(19.844000000000005, 7.108999999999999, 19.962000000000003, 7.093999999999999, 20.408, 7.076);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(20.332, 7.494, 20.256, 7.912, 20.18, 8.328999999999999);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(20.368, 8.480999999999998, 20.472, 8.722999999999999, 20.636, 8.899);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(20.712, 8.937, 20.788, 8.975, 20.864, 9.013);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(20.864, 9.089, 20.864, 9.165, 20.864, 9.241);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(20.94, 9.279, 21.016000000000002, 9.317, 21.092000000000002, 9.355);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(21.092000000000002, 9.659, 21.092000000000002, 9.963000000000001, 21.092000000000002, 10.267000000000001);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(21.130000000000003, 10.267000000000001, 21.168000000000003, 10.267000000000001, 21.206000000000003, 10.267000000000001);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(21.244000000000003, 10.381000000000002, 21.282000000000004, 10.495000000000001, 21.320000000000004, 10.609000000000002);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(21.396000000000004, 10.609000000000002, 21.472000000000005, 10.609000000000002, 21.548000000000005, 10.609000000000002);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(21.510000000000005, 10.685000000000002, 21.472000000000005, 10.761000000000001, 21.434000000000005, 10.837000000000002);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(21.586000000000006, 10.875000000000002, 21.738000000000003, 10.913000000000002, 21.890000000000004, 10.951000000000002);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(21.928000000000004, 11.027000000000003, 21.966000000000005, 11.103000000000002, 22.004000000000005, 11.179000000000002);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(22.080000000000005, 11.179000000000002, 22.156000000000006, 11.179000000000002, 22.232000000000006, 11.179000000000002);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(22.270000000000007, 11.255000000000003, 22.308000000000007, 11.331000000000001, 22.346000000000007, 11.407000000000002);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(22.498000000000008, 11.521000000000003, 22.650000000000006, 11.635000000000002, 22.802000000000007, 11.749000000000002);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(22.802000000000007, 11.825000000000003, 22.802000000000007, 11.901000000000002, 22.802000000000007, 11.977000000000002);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(22.878000000000007, 12.015000000000002, 22.954000000000008, 12.053000000000003, 23.03000000000001, 12.091000000000003);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(23.03000000000001, 12.205000000000004, 23.03000000000001, 12.319000000000003, 23.03000000000001, 12.433000000000003);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(21.83300000000001, 12.409000000000004, 21.232000000000006, 12.605000000000004, 20.40800000000001, 12.889000000000003);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(20.256000000000007, 12.889000000000003, 20.10400000000001, 12.889000000000003, 19.95200000000001, 12.889000000000003);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(19.95200000000001, 12.927000000000003, 19.95200000000001, 12.965000000000003, 19.95200000000001, 13.003000000000004);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(19.800000000000008, 13.041000000000004, 19.64800000000001, 13.079000000000004, 19.49600000000001, 13.117000000000004);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(19.49600000000001, 13.193000000000005, 19.49600000000001, 13.269000000000004, 19.49600000000001, 13.345000000000004);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(19.42000000000001, 13.307000000000004, 19.34400000000001, 13.269000000000004, 19.268000000000008, 13.231000000000003);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(19.268000000000008, 13.269000000000004, 19.268000000000008, 13.307000000000004, 19.268000000000008, 13.345000000000004);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(19.230000000000008, 13.345000000000004, 19.192000000000007, 13.345000000000004, 19.154000000000007, 13.345000000000004);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(19.154000000000007, 13.421000000000005, 19.154000000000007, 13.497000000000003, 19.154000000000007, 13.573000000000004);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(19.116000000000007, 13.573000000000004, 19.078000000000007, 13.573000000000004, 19.040000000000006, 13.573000000000004);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(19.040000000000006, 13.535000000000004, 19.040000000000006, 13.497000000000003, 19.040000000000006, 13.459000000000003);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(18.851000000000006, 13.359000000000004, 18.942000000000007, 13.614000000000003, 18.926000000000005, 13.687000000000003);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(18.611000000000004, 13.770000000000003, 18.671000000000006, 13.719000000000003, 18.584000000000007, 14.029000000000003);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(18.546000000000006, 14.029000000000003, 18.508000000000006, 14.029000000000003, 18.470000000000006, 14.029000000000003);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(18.508000000000006, 14.105000000000004, 18.546000000000006, 14.181000000000003, 18.584000000000007, 14.257000000000003);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(18.508000000000006, 14.257000000000003, 18.432000000000006, 14.257000000000003, 18.356000000000005, 14.257000000000003);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(18.344000000000005, 14.418000000000003, 18.335000000000004, 14.296000000000003, 18.470000000000006, 14.371000000000004);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(18.341000000000005, 14.500000000000004, 18.471000000000007, 14.419000000000004, 18.242000000000004, 14.485000000000005);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(18.204000000000004, 14.675000000000004, 18.166000000000004, 14.865000000000006, 18.128000000000004, 15.055000000000005);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(18.090000000000003, 15.055000000000005, 18.052000000000003, 15.055000000000005, 18.014000000000003, 15.055000000000005);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(18.014000000000003, 15.359000000000005, 18.014000000000003, 15.663000000000006, 18.014000000000003, 15.967000000000006);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(17.976000000000003, 15.967000000000006, 17.938000000000002, 15.967000000000006, 17.900000000000002, 15.967000000000006);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(17.862000000000002, 16.119000000000007, 17.824, 16.271000000000004, 17.786, 16.423000000000005);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(17.748, 16.423000000000005, 17.71, 16.423000000000005, 17.672, 16.423000000000005);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(17.71, 16.499000000000006, 17.748, 16.575000000000006, 17.786, 16.651000000000007);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(17.672, 16.689000000000007, 17.558, 16.727000000000007, 17.444000000000003, 16.765000000000008);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(17.406000000000002, 16.95500000000001, 17.368000000000002, 17.145000000000007, 17.330000000000002, 17.335000000000008);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(17.254, 17.373000000000008, 17.178, 17.41100000000001, 17.102, 17.44900000000001);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(17.102, 17.48700000000001, 17.102, 17.52500000000001, 17.102, 17.56300000000001);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(17.14, 17.56300000000001, 17.178, 17.56300000000001, 17.216, 17.56300000000001);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(17.397000000000002, 17.70900000000001, 16.991, 17.67600000000001, 16.988, 17.67700000000001);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(16.988, 17.943000000000012, 16.988, 18.20900000000001, 16.988, 18.47500000000001);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(16.553, 18.66400000000001, 15.911, 19.17300000000001, 15.847999999999999, 19.72900000000001);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(15.771999999999998, 19.72900000000001, 15.696, 19.72900000000001, 15.62, 19.72900000000001);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(15.475999999999999, 19.98900000000001, 14.79, 20.38500000000001, 15.049999999999999, 20.64100000000001);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(14.973999999999998, 20.64100000000001, 14.898, 20.64100000000001, 14.822, 20.64100000000001);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(14.822, 20.90700000000001, 14.822, 21.17300000000001, 14.822, 21.439000000000007);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(14.86, 21.439000000000007, 14.898, 21.439000000000007, 14.936, 21.439000000000007);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(14.936, 21.515000000000008, 14.936, 21.591000000000008, 14.936, 21.66700000000001);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(14.974, 21.66700000000001, 15.012, 21.66700000000001, 15.05, 21.66700000000001);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(15.05, 21.70500000000001, 15.05, 21.74300000000001, 15.05, 21.78100000000001);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(15.012, 21.78100000000001, 14.974, 21.78100000000001, 14.936, 21.78100000000001);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(14.822, 21.922000000000008, 14.692, 21.899000000000008, 14.594, 22.00900000000001);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(14.594, 22.08500000000001, 14.594, 22.161000000000012, 14.594, 22.237000000000013);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(14.517999999999999, 22.199000000000012, 14.442, 22.161000000000012, 14.366, 22.12300000000001);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(14.328, 22.237000000000013, 14.29, 22.351000000000013, 14.251999999999999, 22.46500000000001);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(14.206, 22.49600000000001, 13.994, 22.29700000000001, 13.796, 22.35100000000001);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(13.796, 22.38900000000001, 13.796, 22.42700000000001, 13.796, 22.46500000000001);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(13.34, 22.46500000000001, 12.883999999999999, 22.46500000000001, 12.427999999999999, 22.46500000000001);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(12.422999999999998, 21.91000000000001, 12.568, 21.35400000000001, 12.77, 20.98300000000001);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(12.808, 20.98300000000001, 12.846, 20.98300000000001, 12.884, 20.98300000000001);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(12.884, 20.90700000000001, 12.884, 20.83100000000001, 12.884, 20.75500000000001);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(12.96, 20.71700000000001, 13.036, 20.67900000000001, 13.112, 20.64100000000001);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(13.233, 20.44400000000001, 13.32, 19.90400000000001, 13.226, 19.84300000000001);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(13.302000000000001, 19.84300000000001, 13.378, 19.84300000000001, 13.454, 19.84300000000001);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(13.476, 19.14000000000001, 13.577, 18.68600000000001, 13.454, 18.02000000000001);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(13.378, 18.02000000000001, 13.302000000000001, 18.02000000000001, 13.226, 18.02000000000001);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(13.104000000000001, 17.91500000000001, 13.340000000000002, 17.90600000000001, 13.340000000000002, 17.90600000000001);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(13.340000000000002, 17.86800000000001, 13.340000000000002, 17.83000000000001, 13.340000000000002, 17.79200000000001);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(13.117, 17.38900000000001, 13.420000000000002, 16.60700000000001, 13.226, 16.19600000000001);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(13.112, 16.120000000000008, 12.998000000000001, 16.044000000000008, 12.884, 15.968000000000009);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(12.597, 15.530000000000008, 12.32, 14.62400000000001, 12.314, 13.917000000000009);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(12.238, 13.955000000000009, 12.162, 13.99300000000001, 12.086, 14.03100000000001);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(12.086, 13.955000000000009, 12.086, 13.87900000000001, 12.086, 13.80300000000001);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(11.82, 13.61300000000001, 11.554, 13.423000000000009, 11.288, 13.23300000000001);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(11.288, 13.157000000000009, 11.288, 13.08100000000001, 11.288, 13.00500000000001);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(11.212, 12.96700000000001, 11.136000000000001, 12.92900000000001, 11.06, 12.891000000000009);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(11.06, 12.815000000000008, 11.06, 12.73900000000001, 11.06, 12.66300000000001);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(11.022, 12.66300000000001, 10.984, 12.66300000000001, 10.946, 12.66300000000001);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(10.87, 12.43500000000001, 10.794, 12.20700000000001, 10.718, 11.97900000000001);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(10.68, 11.97900000000001, 10.642, 11.97900000000001, 10.604, 11.97900000000001);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(10.604, 11.865000000000009, 10.604, 11.75100000000001, 10.604, 11.63700000000001);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(10.489999999999998, 11.599000000000009, 10.376, 11.561000000000009, 10.261999999999999, 11.523000000000009);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(10.299999999999999, 11.447000000000008, 10.338, 11.37100000000001, 10.376, 11.295000000000009);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(10.299999999999999, 11.257000000000009, 10.224, 11.219000000000008, 10.148, 11.181000000000008);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(10.148, 11.105000000000008, 10.148, 11.029000000000009, 10.148, 10.953000000000008);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(10.11, 10.953000000000008, 10.072, 10.953000000000008, 10.033999999999999, 10.953000000000008);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(9.749999999999998, 10.619000000000009, 9.267999999999999, 10.154000000000009, 8.78, 10.041000000000007);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(8.78, 9.965000000000007, 8.78, 9.889000000000008, 8.78, 9.813000000000008);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(8.665, 9.772, 8.551, 9.734, 8.437, 9.696);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(8.437, 9.658, 8.437, 9.62, 8.437, 9.581999999999999);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(8.277, 9.459999999999999, 7.997999999999999, 9.29, 7.866999999999999, 9.467999999999998);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(7.866999999999999, 9.391999999999998, 7.866999999999999, 9.315999999999999, 7.866999999999999, 9.239999999999998);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(7.411, 9.164, 6.955, 9.088, 6.499, 9.012);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(6.499, 8.974, 6.499, 8.936, 6.499, 8.898);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(6.271, 8.822, 6.042, 8.746, 5.814, 8.67);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(5.814, 8.632, 5.814, 8.594, 5.814, 8.556);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(5.207, 8.594, 4.599, 8.632, 3.99, 8.67);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(3.99, 8.632, 3.99, 8.594, 3.99, 8.556);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(3.602, 8.441, 3.248, 8.621, 2.964, 8.442);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(2.888, 8.328, 2.813, 8.214, 2.736, 8.101);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(2.66, 8.138, 2.584, 8.176, 2.508, 8.214);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(2.508, 8.1, 2.508, 7.986000000000001, 2.508, 7.872000000000001);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(2.356, 7.834, 2.204, 7.796, 2.052, 7.758);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(2.014, 7.645, 1.976, 7.53, 1.938, 7.417);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(1.976, 7.417, 2.014, 7.417, 2.052, 7.417);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(2.052, 7.075, 2.052, 6.733, 2.052, 6.391);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(2.0140000000000002, 6.391, 1.976, 6.391, 1.938, 6.391);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(1.938, 6.315, 1.938, 6.239, 1.938, 6.163);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(1.9, 6.163, 1.8619999999999999, 6.163, 1.8239999999999998, 6.163);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(1.8239999999999998, 5.897, 1.8239999999999998, 5.631, 1.8239999999999998, 5.365);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(1.513, 5.185, 1.545, 5.053, 1.026, 5.023);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(1.026, 5.061, 1.026, 5.098999999999999, 1.026, 5.137);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(0.95, 5.175, 0.874, 5.213, 0.798, 5.251);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(0.798, 5.175000000000001, 0.798, 5.099, 0.798, 5.023000000000001);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(0.569, 4.958, 0.7, 5.037, 0.57, 4.909);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(0.608, 4.909, 0.6459999999999999, 4.909, 0.6839999999999999, 4.909);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(0.6839999999999999, 4.795, 0.6839999999999999, 4.681, 0.6839999999999999, 4.567);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(0.49399999999999994, 4.567, 0.30399999999999994, 4.567, 0.11399999999999999, 4.567);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(0.076, 4.453, 0.038, 4.339, 0, 4.226);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(0.038, 4.226, 0.076, 4.226, 0.114, 4.226);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(0.114, 4.074, 0.114, 3.922, 0.114, 3.77);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(0.228, 3.732, 0.342, 3.694, 0.456, 3.656);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(0.67, 3.484, 0.76, 3.218, 0.798, 2.858);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(0.988, 2.858, 1.178, 2.858, 1.3679999999999999, 2.858);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(1.3679999999999999, 2.782, 1.3679999999999999, 2.706, 1.3679999999999999, 2.63);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(1.482, 2.63, 1.5959999999999999, 2.63, 1.71, 2.63);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(1.71, 2.554, 1.71, 2.4779999999999998, 1.71, 2.4019999999999997);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(1.8679999999999999, 2.4309999999999996, 1.697, 2.417, 1.824, 2.5159999999999996);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(1.976, 2.44, 2.128, 2.364, 2.28, 2.288);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(2.28, 2.25, 2.28, 2.2119999999999997, 2.28, 2.174);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(2.356, 2.174, 2.432, 2.174, 2.508, 2.174);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(2.573, 1.896, 2.628, 1.923, 2.736, 1.718);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(2.888, 1.832, 3.041, 1.946, 3.192, 2.06);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(3.192, 2.098, 3.192, 2.136, 3.192, 2.174);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(3.269, 2.136, 3.344, 2.098, 3.42, 2.06);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(3.42, 2.136, 3.42, 2.212, 3.42, 2.2880000000000003);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(3.551, 2.42, 3.728, 2.389, 3.99, 2.402);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(3.99, 2.326, 3.99, 2.25, 3.99, 2.174);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(4.12, 2.27, 4.007, 2.159, 4.104, 2.288);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(4.5200000000000005, 2.694, 4.5520000000000005, 3.5309999999999997, 4.674, 4.226);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(4.788, 4.264, 4.902, 4.302, 5.016, 4.34);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(5.055, 4.453, 5.092, 4.567, 5.13, 4.681);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(5.244, 4.643, 5.358, 4.605, 5.4719999999999995, 4.567);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(5.481, 4.867, 5.515999999999999, 4.955, 5.585999999999999, 5.1370000000000005);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(5.8149999999999995, 5.072, 5.909, 5.0520000000000005, 6.042, 4.909000000000001);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(6.042, 4.833000000000001, 6.042, 4.757000000000001, 6.042, 4.681000000000001);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(6.08, 4.681000000000001, 6.117999999999999, 4.681000000000001, 6.156, 4.681000000000001);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(6.156, 4.719000000000001, 6.156, 4.757000000000001, 6.156, 4.795000000000001);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(6.231999999999999, 4.757000000000001, 6.308, 4.719000000000001, 6.3839999999999995, 4.681000000000001);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(6.3839999999999995, 4.719000000000001, 6.3839999999999995, 4.757000000000001, 6.3839999999999995, 4.795000000000001);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(6.5089999999999995, 4.897000000000001, 6.4079999999999995, 4.775000000000001, 6.497999999999999, 4.909000000000001);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(6.459999999999999, 4.909000000000001, 6.422, 4.909000000000001, 6.3839999999999995, 4.909000000000001);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(6.273, 5.098, 6.549, 5.005, 6.613, 5.023);
    ctx.lineTo(6.727, 4.909);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(6.765000000000001, 5.099, 6.803, 5.289, 6.841, 5.479);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(6.955, 5.517, 7.069, 5.555, 7.183, 5.593);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(7.183, 5.631, 7.183, 5.669, 7.183, 5.707);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(7.322, 5.818, 7.404, 5.787, 7.5249999999999995, 5.935);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(7.866999999999999, 5.973, 8.209, 6.010999999999999, 8.551, 6.0489999999999995);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(8.589, 5.935, 8.627, 5.821, 8.665000000000001, 5.707);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(8.936, 5.684, 8.947, 5.66, 9.121, 5.593);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(9.011000000000001, 5.447, 8.871, 5.475, 8.779, 5.365);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(8.779, 5.289000000000001, 8.779, 5.213, 8.779, 5.1370000000000005);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(8.665, 5.099, 8.551, 5.061, 8.437, 5.023);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(8.442, 4.58, 8.474, 4.454, 8.665, 4.226);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(8.741, 4.188, 8.816999999999998, 4.15, 8.892999999999999, 4.112);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(8.855, 3.998, 8.817, 3.883, 8.779, 3.77);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(8.779, 3.77, 8.967, 3.622, 9.007, 3.542);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(8.663, 3.463, 8.258, 2.789, 7.981, 3.085);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(7.981, 3.009, 7.981, 2.933, 7.981, 2.8569999999999998);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(7.796, 2.98, 7.92, 3.051, 7.867, 3.085);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(7.795, 3.131, 7.627, 2.877, 7.411, 2.971);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(7.335, 3.085, 7.259, 3.2, 7.183, 3.313);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(7.02, 3.367, 7.021, 3.121, 6.955, 3.085);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(6.8790000000000004, 3.085, 6.803, 3.085, 6.727, 3.085);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(6.727, 3.047, 6.727, 3.009, 6.727, 2.971);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(6.362, 2.781, 6.006, 2.7560000000000002, 5.473000000000001, 2.743);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(5.473000000000001, 2.667, 5.473000000000001, 2.5909999999999997, 5.473000000000001, 2.5149999999999997);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(5.549, 2.5149999999999997, 5.625000000000001, 2.5149999999999997, 5.7010000000000005, 2.5149999999999997);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(5.793, 2.1479999999999997, 5.993, 2.1099999999999994, 6.157000000000001, 1.8309999999999995);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(6.081000000000001, 1.8309999999999995, 6.005000000000001, 1.8309999999999995, 5.929000000000001, 1.8309999999999995);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(5.883000000000001, 1.3729999999999996, 5.7970000000000015, 1.4189999999999996, 5.929000000000001, 1.0329999999999995);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(6.004, 1.072, 6.081, 1.11, 6.157, 1.148);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(6.195, 1.262, 6.232, 1.376, 6.271, 1.49);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(6.3469999999999995, 1.49, 6.423, 1.49, 6.499, 1.49);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(6.46, 1.566, 6.423, 1.642, 6.385, 1.718);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(6.423, 1.718, 6.460999999999999, 1.718, 6.499, 1.718);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(6.632, 1.873, 6.707, 1.892, 6.955, 1.946);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(6.955, 1.8319999999999999, 6.955, 1.718, 6.955, 1.6039999999999999);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(7.107, 1.6039999999999999, 7.259, 1.6039999999999999, 7.4110000000000005, 1.6039999999999999);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(7.373, 1.49, 7.335, 1.376, 7.297, 1.262);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(7.373, 1.3, 7.449, 1.338, 7.525, 1.376);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(7.525, 1.3379999999999999, 7.525, 1.2999999999999998, 7.525, 1.2619999999999998);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(7.563000000000001, 1.2619999999999998, 7.601, 1.2619999999999998, 7.639, 1.2619999999999998);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(7.601, 1.0719999999999998, 7.563000000000001, 0.8819999999999998, 7.525, 0.6919999999999998);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(7.563000000000001, 0.6919999999999998, 7.601, 0.6919999999999998, 7.639, 0.6919999999999998);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(7.769, 0.5619999999999998, 7.639, 0.6469999999999998, 7.867, 0.5779999999999998);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(7.867, 0.5019999999999999, 7.867, 0.4259999999999998, 7.867, 0.34999999999999987);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(8.358, 0.48099999999999987, 8.256, 0.32099999999999984, 8.665, 0.12199999999999986);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(8.665, 0.08399999999999985, 8.665, 0.04599999999999986, 8.665, 0.007999999999999854);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(8.827, -0.04900000000000015, 8.828999999999999, 0.21099999999999985, 8.892999999999999, 0.23599999999999988);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(9.26, 0.383, 9.427, 0.259, 9.691, 0.351);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(9.833, 0.7629999999999999, 9.678, 0.997, 9.805000000000001, 1.376);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(10.909000000000002, 0.9259999999999999, 11.771, 1.458, 12.769000000000002, 1.718);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(12.906000000000002, 1.4689999999999999, 13.020000000000001, 1.343, 13.339000000000002, 1.262);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(13.339000000000002, 1.3, 13.339000000000002, 1.338, 13.339000000000002, 1.3760000000000001);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(13.491000000000001, 1.3760000000000001, 13.643000000000002, 1.3760000000000001, 13.795000000000002, 1.3760000000000001);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(13.795000000000002, 1.4140000000000001, 13.795000000000002, 1.4520000000000002, 13.795000000000002, 1.4900000000000002);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(14.232, 1.7, 14.57, 1.656, 14.708, 2.174);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.restore();
    ctx.restore();
}

function paintLake() {

    // If the shape is clicked, display a fact
    // and paint the lake.
    // Display a fact.
    alert("Lake Michigan is one of the five Great Lakes of America.");

    // Fill the lake with blue.
    ctx.fillStyle = "blue";
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.scale(200, 200);
}

function makeLake() {

    // These methods draw the shape of the lake.

}
function zoom(){
 ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
 ctx.scale(3,3);
 draw(ctx);
}
```

```html
<body onload="init()">
 <h1>
  Lake Michigan
 </h1>
 <button onclick='zoom()'>zoom</button>
 <canvas id="canvas" width="250" height="250" onclick="paintLake()">
 </canvas>
 <p>
    Click on the lake to learn a fact about Lake Michigan.
 </p>
</body>
```

Use [ctx.scale(x,y)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/scale) to zoom canvas.

Comment: I want to zoom/increase the view box size and map should be adjusted to 100% of width and height of the view box size. Can you please do it and map should not cut  when I zoom more

Comment: You need to increase the canvas size as well??

Comment: I think, Yes. That is my actual requirement. I understand after looking at your answer. The black colored map should be 100% of the view box. When I mention any view box size, the map should be adjusted to 100% as svgs